# Adding content to a page through a module

Tags: 6, nodes

I just want to echo some words when a certain node comes up.

Currently however it doesn't echo within the content section, but above the header.

How do I get my module to echo the words at the top of the content section?

Comment: How are you "echoing words" currently? Are you wanting to echo the same words? or different words for each node?  Need more description... more details.

Answer (score 1):

If the content is always static then you can look into adding it to a theme template file (by creating a subtheme).

Or you could add some php as part of preprocess_node in template.php to append/prepend the text to the content/body array.